# Offset within For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to go through a range and determine if a cell contains a "#" while also going through the cell beside it and determining if it is empty. If it contains "#" and is not empty then I want it to perform the function in the If statement. When I run the code it comes up with a mismatch error on where the If statement starts. Any help?

```
    Dim cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In Range("S2:S10000")
        If InStr(cel.Value, "#") > 0 And IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, -1)) = False Then
           cel.Select
            Selection.offset(0,-1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Do any of your cells have an error in them?

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention that. The # is supposed to find all those cells with #N/A in them. Is there an easier way to find those cells?

Comment: `IsError(cel.value)`

Comment: VBA will interpret '#N/A' as an error code, not text

Comment: #N/A is a `Variant/Error`, not a string; you can only compare it to another `Variant/Error` value, and any string or arithmetic operators used with it will throw a type mismatch error.

Comment: That said avoid the mind-bending select +offset; just do `cel.Offset` instead of selecting and then going late-bound against `Selection`

Comment: Write (nest) two If statements: *Line 1)* `If CVErr(cel.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then`, *Line 2)* `If Not IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, -1)) Then`.